# How to re-format column of text from space delinitation to hyphen?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

So here is what the data looks like:

[image]

What I need is a way to convert the spaces in the **Title** column, which would be easy if I also didn't have a | character. This appears to need some VBA to conver it to the format of the **Handle** column?

I tried this `=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(B2," ","-",4))` with no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm not working for some reason .,. ? Its only substituting the first instance of " "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, use substitute() twice:

[image]

To save you typing:

```
SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B1," | "," ")," ","-")
```

Edit based on comments:
And if you need the final result in lower case then:

```
=lower(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B1," | "," ")," ","-"))
```

I used the inner substitute:

```
SUBSTITUTE(B1," | "," ")
```

to replace the space pipe space " | " with just a space,

Then the outer substitute to replace all the spaces with "-".

Comment: This is exactly it, I would never have thought to nest substitute. Can you explain a bit how this works?

Comment: @HelloWorld - use Formulas > Evaluate Formula perhaps to see it in action.